# Can we get numbered rankings on the leaderboard

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash

Can we have all the sites (auto) ranked on the [Winterbash Leaderboard page](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard)?

[image]

It would make it easier to know the exact position of a site

Any thoughts/opinions on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the numbers using [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

We can target all the list items except the first by using `:not(:first-child)`, then simply set a counter and use it as the content of a pseudo-element.

The important parts are just the `counter-*` rules, the rest is mostly positioning and styling.

```css
body {
    counter-reset: rank;
}

.lb-row:not(:first-child):before {
    counter-increment: rank; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
    content: counter(rank); 

    /* layout */
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    width: 30px;

    /* style */
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.lb-row {
    position: relative /* we need this to position the number */
}
```

Adding that as a user style gives us...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In case such feature won't be added, you can execute the following JS code to get the ranks:

```js
$(".lb-row").each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    var index = row.index();
    if (index > 0) {
        var iconCell = row.find(".lb-icon");
        if (iconCell.length == 1) {
            var rankDiv = $("<div></div>");
            rankDiv.css({
                "position": "absolute", 
                "width": "70px", 
                "height": "70px", 
                "line-height": "70px", 
                "text-align": "center", 
                "vertical-align": "middle", 
                "font-size": "25px", 
                "color": "#000"
            });
            rankDiv.text("#" + index);
            iconCell.prepend(rankDiv);
        }
    }
});
```

This can be executed via any modern browser's developer console. It will show the rank of each site in the middle of its icon. Not ideal, but should be clear enough, and took the couple of minutes I had to spare. :)

Comment: No need for JS [when you can do it with CSS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304915/307988). Have a +1 anyway though ;)

Comment: @Cai neat! I'm not really CSS guru... :/

Comment: I've accepted @Cai answer (as it performs better), however, your answer was much easier for me to put into place - and it does the trick, therefore the +1

Comment: @WELZ cheers, glad I could help. :)